# Translate a FOR to assembler

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I need to translate what is commented within the method, to assembler. I have a roughly idea, but can't.

Anyone can help me please? Is for an Intel x32 architecture:

```
int 
secuencia ( int n, EXPRESION * * o )
{
  int a, i;
//--- Translate from here ...
  for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
    a = evaluarExpresion( *o );
    o++;
  }
  return a ;
//--- ... until here.
}
```

Translated code must be within __asm as:

```
__asm {
        translated code
}
```

Thank you,

FINAL UPDATE:

This is the final version, working and commented, thanks to all for your help :)

```
int
secuencia ( int n, EXPRESION * * o )
{
    int a = 0, i;
    __asm
    {
        mov dword ptr [i],0             ; int i = 0
        jmp salto1
        ciclo1:
        mov eax,dword ptr [i]           
        add eax,1                       ; increment in 1 the value of i
        mov dword ptr [i],eax           ; i++
        salto1: 
        mov eax,dword ptr [i]           
        cmp eax,dword ptr [n]           ; Compare i and n
        jge final                       ; If is greater goes to 'final'
        mov eax,dword ptr [o] 
        mov ecx,dword ptr [eax]         ; Recover * o (its value)
        push ecx                        ; Make push of * o (At the stack, its value)
        call evaluarExpresion           ; call evaluarExpresion( * o )
        add esp,4                       ; Recover memory from the stack (4KB corresponding to the * o pointer)
        mov dword ptr [a],eax           ; Save the result of evaluarExpresion as the value of a
        mov eax,dword ptr [o]           ; extract the pointer to o
        add eax,4                       ; increment the pointer by a factor of 4 (next of the actual pointed by *o)
        mov dword ptr [o],eax           ; o++
        jmp ciclo1                      ; repeat
        final:                          ; for's final
        mov eax,dword ptr [a]           ; return a - it save the return value at the eax registry (by convention this is where the result must be stored)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? If it is, don't expect someone to just give you the answer. Show what you have so far.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? The compiler is perfectly capable of doing this for you. Is there some reason the compiler output is not good enough?

Comment: It would be faster to get `gcc` to do your homework for you than to ask a site of programming Q&A. Try `man gcc`.

Comment: Its self homework from Professional Assembly... but I'm stucked!

Comment: You should "pop ecx" after calling evaluarExpresion.  Also, I don't think you need to muck with ebp/esp like that...

Comment: For the benefit of those who don't speak Spanish, would you consider translating the comments into English?  I'd do it myself except that doesn't seem like a valid reason for me to edit a post, etiquette-wise

Comment: Already done Nathan, fully working and documented (maybe for the help of others like me).

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essentially in assembly languages, strictly speaking there isn't a notion of a loop the same way there would be in a higher level language.  It's all implemented with jumps (eg. as a "`goto`"...)

That said, x86 has some instructions with the assumption that you'll be writing "loops", implicitly using the register `ECX` as a loop counter.

Some examples:

```
    mov ecx, 5         ; ecx = 5
.label:
    ; Loop body code goes here
    ; ECX will start out as 5, then 4, then 3, then 1...
    loop .label        ; if (--ecx) goto .label;
```

Or:

```
    jecxz .loop_end    ; if (!ecx) goto .loop_end;
.loop_start:
    ; Loop body goes here
    loop .loop_start   ; if (--ecx) goto .loop_start;
.loop_end:
```

And, if you don't like this `loop` instruction thing counting backwards...  You can write something like:

```
    xor ecx, ecx       ; ecx = 0
.loop_start:
    cmp ecx, 5         ; do (ecx-5) discarding result, then set FLAGS
    jz .loop_end       ; if (ecx-5) was zero (eg. ecx == 5), jump to .loop_end
    ; Loop body goes here.
    inc ecx            ; ecx++
    jmp .loop_start
.loop_end:
```

This would be closer to the typical `for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) { }`

Comment: I agree... asveikau: That's a very nice explanation, now I now where to begin. Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 6):

Note that

```
for (init; cond; advance) {
    ...
}
```

is essentially syntactic sugar for

```
init;
while(cond) {
   ...
   advance;
}
```

which should be easy enough to translate into assembly language if you've been paying any attention in class.

Comment: Thanks, so I can use the registries... decrement and jumps... umm now I have a shape

Answer (score 5):

Use gcc to generate the assembly code

```
gcc -S -c sample.c
```

man gcc is your friend

Comment: Or: Man, gcc is your friend! LOL, a compiler that generates assembly language. Who would have thought it.

Comment: Haha, gcc's manpage might possibly be useful, but note that gcc's manpage is 12,838 lines! The "-S" option doesn't even show up until the 678th line!

Comment: @rascher having to read? Perish the thought! Regex-compatible searching? Heresy! ;)

Answer (score 2):

For that you would probably use the loop instruction that decrements the ecx (often called, extended counter) at each loop and goes out when ecx reaches zero.But why use inline asm for it anyway? I'm pretty sure something as simple as that will be optimized correctly by the compiler...

(We say x86 architecture, because it's based on 80x86 computers, but it's an "ok" mistake =p)

Comment: Jejej thanks... I build software for a few years.. but now is when I'm starting to self study about PC Architecture, Assembler and more.